# MongoDB and C#, how to compare by day of week

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

In C# I have to get all documents, that have a date property that falls on a specific day of week (Monday for example).

How can I do that? I tried simply comparing the DayOfWeek property like this:

```
Builders<TEntity>.Filter.Where(x=>x.Start.DayOfWeek == weekday);
```

But I get an error:

```
Convert({document}{Start}.DayOfWeek) is not supported.
```

"weekday" is a DayOfWeek, "DayOfWeek.Monday" for example.

Comment: what is the value of `weekday` ?

Comment: It's a weekday, "DayOfWeek.Monday" for example. Would it work if I simply convert it to its integer value? I have to try that :)

Comment: I have to write a negative comment on this post. I did not think of how mongodb stores dates. They are saved as timestams, which of course don't have a "dayOfWeek" parameter associated with it. I think this might be a harder problem than I realised.

Answer (score 0):

You can use MongoDB Driver Linq3.
You can reference this link: https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/how-to-filter-by-day-of-week/148776